# Compiler seeming to change my const parameter

Tags: c++, templates, constants

I am trying to use my template class's Contains() method, but I am getting a strange argument conversion error.

> error C2664: 'bool DynamicArray::Contains(const E) const'
>   : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const Joint *' to 'Joint *const ' 
>   with E=Joint
>   Conversion loses qualifiers

Here is the relevant template class code.

```
template <class E>
class DynamicArray
{
    bool Contains (const E element) const;

    // Other code...
};

template <class E>
bool DynamicArray<E>::Contains(const E element) const
{
     // Other code...
}
```

The call made to the Contains method is done so here

```
bool ASMState::AnimatesJoint(const Joint* pJoint) const
{
    return m_animatedJoints.Contains(pJoint);
}
```

Relevant template class code in ASMState.h

```
class ASMState
{
    DynamicArray<Joint*> m_animatedJoints;

    // Other members...

    bool AnimatesJoint(const Joint* pJoint) const;

    // Other methods...
};
```

If I remove the const in the AnimatesJoint function signature like so, `bool ASMState::AnimatesJoint(Joint* pJoint) const` then the code compiles. I would like to keep the const there if I can, but I do not know why that parameter seems to change from what I wrote. That is, from `const Joint *` to `Joint *const` according to the compiler.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express

Comment: The question is not a duplicate, as the problem leading to the compiler error is not solved by one of the linked threads. It's not the `Joint *` to `Joint * const` conversion which leads to  the error, but the invalid `Joint const *` to `Joint *` conversion. And the latter issue is not different than for any other (non-pointer) type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class template `DynamicArray` deduces the type `E` as `Joint *`, and in the member function `Contains` you basically add a `const` to it. Now, as it was mentioned in the comments and already stated by the compiler error, this does not lead to `const Joint*` (which is the same as `Joint const*`), but rather to `Joint * const` -- adding a `const` does not correspond to a textual replacement where you'd simply replace `E` by your pointer type.

However, the problem here is not in adding the `const` to the pointer type taken by the function `Contains`, because this cast is allowed. The problem is rather that you pass a const pointer to the function `Contains`, but it is actually expecting a non-const pointer -- it's the cast from `const Joint*` to `Joint *` that is disallowed.

This is why removing the `const` in `Contains(const E)` will not solve this specific problem. I'd strongly suggest it nevertheless, because taking a parameter by const-value is almost never useful.

Rather, as you've already written, you need to remove the `const` in the function `AnimatesJoint(const Joint* pJoint)`.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that `bool Contains (const E element) const` expects an input of type `const E`, whereas in

```
return m_animatedJoints.Contains(pJoint);
```

you are passing an input of type `const E *`, in other words a pointer. Perhaps the solution is to change this line to:

```
return m_animatedJoints.Contains(*pJoint);
```

I guess that the error you are getting is because the compiler is trying to pass the input `pJoint` as `const E` where `E = ... * const`, i.e. a constant pointer.

Comment: Do you know how type deduction works?